# Answer a phone call from iPhone screen with airpods in without disconnection from airpods

Tags: iphone, airpods

Sometimes my Airpods do not respond to my taps, so I have gotten into the habit of answering phone calls from the iPhone screen if a call comes in while I am wearing the Airpods. However, if I answer from the phone, the device seems to think I want to talk through the phone itself, and automatically disconnects me from the Airpods. I have to then press the  "Speaker" button, and then choose my Airpods from the list, and only then am I able to talk through the Airpods.

My question is, is it possible to answer the phone from the screen while the Airpods are connected *without* being disconnected? With the wired Apple earphones, this does not happen. I.e., if you have them plugged in and answer a call, the earphones are not suddenly bypassed for the device speaker and mic. If this is not a bug, I am sure Apple has their reasons for this behavior, but I wonder if there is a workaround or a setting I can tweak. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apple assumes that wherever you answer from is where you want to hear the audio.

The fact that your AirPods are unresponsive to your taps is a separate issue (maybe Apple will address in future updates). The expected behavior is that if you want to answer on your AirPods, you'll tap on them.

Comment: That’s it basically. Summed up what I was about to answer with.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Since this does not apply to wired headphones, the behavior was surprising to me (though I understand that the two types of headphones are very different).

Comment: @elethan well if you think about the AirPods as being more of a Bluetooth speaker than actual earphones it might make more sense. With the wired ones they can assume you have them in your ears, whereas there’s no indication of where the AirPods are or who’s ears they’re in. Obviously that’s not technical, but hopefully you know what I mean.

Comment: @Andre agreed. While it's unlikely your AirPods are connected without being in your ears (they should be in your case if they aren't in your ears IMO), some people may place them on a table without putting them in case etc.

Comment: @Andregood point! Makes sense!